# How can I execute ajax function right away after loading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(refreshPartial, 30000)
});
```

This will start executing function 3 second after page is loaded.
But what if I want it to execute right away after the page is loaded and keep executing 3 seconds after that?
How can I change this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(refreshPartial, 30000);
    refreshPartial();
});
```

*That wasn't the hardest one...*

Answer (score 0):

You can nothing stops you. Don't use the setInterval. Just call the function straight away, like:

> refreshPartial()

If it gets over in less than 3 seconds, you save the time. There is no real need to call the same function again after 3 seconds.